# Generate classes from XML : xsd.exe not found

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, class, xsd

I would like to generate classes from an XML file.
I tried using the command prompt but the xsd function cannot be found, I got this message :

> 'xsd' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I tried this way too : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
But I don't have the "Paste Special" menu.

How can I install XSd command ? (my .NET Framework is up to date, my version is 4.5)
How can I add the "Past Special" menu ?
I working on VS Ultimate 2012

Comment: use the developer command for visual studio instead of the default cmd.exe

Comment: Thank you for your comment (it's been 6.5 years now, I don't even remember which project it is ^^)

Answer (score 15):

xsd.exe isn't in your path by default. It should be available in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v???\bin
```

What `v???` actually is will vary depending on the version of the framework you have installed.

As Nguyễn Đức Tâm points out in their comment, you may find it in
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs` these days, though it's still in `Program Files (x86)` for me.

Alternatively, search for `Developer Command Prompt for VS20xx" in the start menu (where`xx`depends on the version of Visual Studio that you are running). This runs a`cmd`with your path set up to access development tools such as`xsd` removing the need to find it.

Comment: Microsoft SDKs is in Program Files instead of (x86)

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm, it's still in `Program Files (x86)` for me, but I've updated this answer to reflect what you have found as it's a six year old answer and so needed updating.

Comment: Actually, ``Microsoft SDKs`` is in both ``Program Files`` and ``x86``. I just checked it. Your answer is still up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Further adding to the above solution, run Developer Command Prompt for VS20xx as Admin.